# Can't create new windows phone apps using visual studio 2013 why?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2013

Whenever I try to create a new windows phone 8 app this error occur

> > the project file could not be loaded. root element is missing

which i have no idea why this happens,, it only happens with windows phone apps and i am currently running on windows 8 !

Here is the error message snap-shot, any help will be greatly appreciated.[image: this is the error message that i get]

Comment: Why is your csproj inside a temp folder?

Comment: I have no idea... is there a way to change this odd behavior ?